# Turn uppercase H1, H2,... tags into capitalized title with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I would like to turn uppercase h1, h2,... tags into capitalized text with PHP. I'm close, but not there yet. The below snippet does not turn the first character of "LOREM" into uppercase (probably because it tries to uppercase '<'). It would be easy to modify the callback PHP function, but I wish I could do this by only modifying the regex piece:

```
$var = "
<h1>LOREM IPSUM DOLORES AMET</h1>
THIS IS SOME TEXT
<H2>LOREM IPSUM DOLORES AMET</H2>";

$line = preg_replace_callback(
    '/<h[1-9]>(.*)\>/i',
    function ($matches) {
        return ucfirst(strtolower($matches[0]));
    },
    $var
);

print($line);
```

Results in:

```
<h1>lorem ipsum dolores amet</h1>
THIS IS SOME TEXT
<H2>lorem ipsum dolores amet</H2>
```

Desired output:

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolores amet</h1>
THIS IS SOME TEXT
<H2>Lorem ipsum dolores amet</H2>
```

Comment: `$matches[0]` is the entire match; if you want the first capture group that'd be `$matches[1]`.

Comment: While I write an answer, read this:

[Don't parse HTML with regex. Ever.][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @deceze yep, but it has some drawbacks.

Comment: @Tek Thanks for bringing that to my attention. Luckily, there will be human verification after the modification, to guarantee quality of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `DOMDocument`

```
<?php

        $var = "
<h1>LOREM IPSUM DOLORES AMET</h1>
THIS IS SOME TEXT
<H2>LOREM IPSUM DOLORES AMET</H2>";

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($var);

        $tags = array("h1", "h2");
        //loop thru all h1 and h2 tags

        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            //get all elements of the current tag
            $elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tag);
            //if we found at least 1 element
            if (!empty($elements)) {
                //loop thru each element of the given tag
                foreach ($elements as $element) {
                    //run ucfirst on the nodevalue
                    //which is equivalent to the "textContent" property of a DOM node
                $element->nodeValue = ucfirst(strtolower($element->nodeValue));
                }
            }
        }

$html = $dom->saveHTML();
//remove extra markup
$html = str_replace("</body></html>","",substr($html,strpos($html,"<h1>"));
echo $html;

<h1>Lorem ipsum dolores amet</h1>
THIS IS SOME TEXT
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolores amet</h2>
```

Comment: After reading one should never use regex to parse HTML, this solution has been picked as the right answer, even-though it doesn't answer the question literally.

Comment: glad it worked for you. unless the task is mindnumbingly simple, I'd always prefer a DOM parser over regex. Thats part of the fun of stack overflow! instead of a "heres how you do that" answer you may get a "why would you do it *that* way? do it **this** way this instead" answer

Answer (score 3):

Your are returning the entire match using `$matches[0]`. Use [lookarounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) in this case.

I would recommend using a capturing group within the first `<h...>` tag so you can use it as a backreference; therefore you will match the same ending tag matched from that group.

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('~<h([1-9])>\K[^<]++(?=</h\1>)~i', 
      function($m) {
         return ucfirst(strtolower($m[0]));
      }, $text);
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/244868)

Although you can do this using regex, I recommend utilizing [**`DOM`**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for this.

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
    <h1>LOREM IPSUM DOLORES AMET</h1>
    THIS IS SOME TEXT
    <H2>LOREM IPSUM DOLORES AMET</H2>
');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//h1|//h2|//h3|//h4|//h5|//h6');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $node->nodeValue = ucfirst(strtolower($node->nodeValue));
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not `$matches[0]`, it's `$matches[1]`. `matches[0]` refers to the entire match (ie, `ucfirst`, `strtolower` functions applies to the whole match) whereas `$matches[1]` refers to the characters which are present inside the group index 1. Because we included `<h[1-9]>` in the regex, it matches the starting `<h>` tags. But in the replacement part, we included only  the group index 1 like `ucfirst(strtolower($matches[1]))`. So the starting `<h>` tags got removed. See the below example.

```
$var = "
<h1>LOREM IPSUM DOLORES AMET</h1>
THIS IS SOME TEXT
<H2>LOREM IPSUM DOLORES AMET</H2>";

$line = preg_replace_callback(
    '/<h[1-9]>(.*)\>/i',
    function ($matches) {
        return ucfirst(strtolower($matches[1]));
    },
    $var
);

print($line);
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolores amet</h1
THIS IS SOME TEXT
Lorem ipsum dolores amet</h2
```

But the above replaces the  `<h1>` tags at the first too. So i recommend you the below which applies `strtolower`, `ucfirst` functions only to the part within the `<h>` tags.

```
$var = "
<h1>LOREM IPSUM DOLORES AMET</h1>
THIS IS SOME TEXT
<H2>LOREM IPSUM DOLORES AMET</H2>";

$line = preg_replace_callback(
        '/<h[1-9]>\K.*?(?=<)/i',
        function ($matches) {
            return ucfirst(strtolower($matches[0]));
        },
        $var
);

print($line);
```

Output:

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolores amet</h1>
THIS IS SOME TEXT
<H2>Lorem ipsum dolores amet</H2>
```

`\K` discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final. `.*?` would do a non-greedy match of any character zero or more times `(?=<)` upto a literal `<` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

No regex needed. [Obligatory link. Don't use regex to parse HTML. Ever.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

## [DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xHNxmG)

```
<?php

$HTMLString = <<<HTML

<h1>lorem ipsum dolores amet</h1>
THIS IS SOME TEXT
<h2>lorem ipsum dolores amet</h2>

HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTML($HTMLString);

//You can also use xpath. Loop results after using this instead:
//$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
//$nodeList= $xpath->query(//h2);

$nodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h2');

foreach ($nodeList as $node) {

    $stringArray = explode(' ', $node->nodeValue);
    $stringArray[0] = ucfirst($stringArray[0]);
    $capitalizedSentence = implode(' ', $stringArray);
    echo $capitalizedSentence;
}
```

From:

## lorem ipsum dolores amet

To:

## Lorem ipsum dolores amet